# add properties of object in array and get single object by loadash

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

I am using loadash in my project 
i have object in array like this

```
[{
    "rating": {
        "time_to_table": 5,
        "value_for_money": 5,
        "innovation": 5,
        "plating_decoration": 5,
        "taste": 5
    }
}, {
    "rating": {
        "time_to_table": 0,
        "value_for_money": 3,
        "innovation": 2,
        "plating_decoration": 2,
        "taste": 4
    }
}]
```

Now I want output like this by adding each property and want single object like this

```
"rating": {
    "time_to_table": 5,
    "value_for_money": 8,
    "innovation": 7,
    "plating_decoration": 7,
    "taste": 9
}
```

I have tried this

```
        var obj = {
            "time_to_table": 0,
            "value_for_money": 0,
            "innovation": 0,
            "plating_decoration": 0,
            "taste": 0,
            "total" : 5 * data.length
        }

        _.forEach(data,function(d){          
            obj.time_to_table += d.rating.time_to_table;
            obj.value_for_money += d.rating.value_for_money;
            obj.innovation += d.rating.innovation;
            obj.plating_decoration += d.rating.plating_decoration;
            obj.taste += d.rating.taste;
        });
```

Comment: Can it be done with plain javascript ?

Comment: I can loop all array and push , but i want something like reduce @Weedoze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Lodash` you can do this using `reduce()` and `mergeWith()` that takes custom function as parameter.

```js
var data = [{"rating":{"time_to_table":5,"value_for_money":5,"innovation":5,"plating_decoration":5,"taste":5}},{"rating":{"time_to_table":0,"value_for_money":3,"innovation":2,"plating_decoration":2,"taste":4}}]

var result = _.reduce(data, function(r, e, i) {
  if(i != 0) _.mergeWith(r.rating, e.rating, (a, b) => a + b)
  return r;
}, data[0])

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `Array#reduce()` and `Object.keys()`

```js
const data = [{rating:{time_to_table:5,value_for_money:5,innovation:5,plating_decoration:5,taste:5}},{rating:{time_to_table:0,value_for_money:3,innovation:2,plating_decoration:2,taste:4}}];

let finalObject = data.reduce((o, c) => {
  Object.keys(c.rating).forEach(k => {
    o.rating[k] = o.rating[k] || 0;
    o.rating[k] += c.rating[k];
  });
  return o;
}, { rating: {} })

console.log(finalObject);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce, and having as many property as you want in your objects.

The following function doesn't require to know anything about the kind of object you are passing, because there are no hardcoded properties

```js
const arr = [{
    "rating": {
        "time_to_table": 5,
        "value_for_money": 5,
        "innovation": 5,
        "plating_decoration": 5,
        "taste": 5
    }, 
    a: {b: 1, c: 2}
}, {
    "rating": {
        "time_to_table": 0,
        "value_for_money": 3,
        "innovation": 2,
        "plating_decoration": 2,
        "taste": 4
    },
    a: {b: 3, c: 0}
}];

const result = arr.reduce(fn, {})

function fn (acc, val) {
  for (let x in val) {
    acc[x] = acc[x] || {};
    for (let y in val[x]) {
      acc[x][y] = acc[x][y] || 0;
      acc[x][y] += val[x][y];
    }
  }
  
  return acc;
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array#reduce` solution.

```js
var arr = [{"rating":{"time_to_table":5,"value_for_money":5,"innovation":5,"plating_decoration":5,"taste":5}},{"rating":{"time_to_table":0,"value_for_money":3,"innovation":2,"plating_decoration":2,"taste":4}}], obj = arr[0]; arr.splice(0,1);

var res = arr.reduce(function(s, a) {
  Object.keys(a.rating).forEach(function(v) {
    s.rating[v] += a.rating[v];
  })
  return s;
}, obj);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive approach for arbitrary nested object, to collect and sum values in the objects.

```js
var data = [{ rating: { time_to_table: 5, value_for_money: 5, innovation: 5, plating_decoration: 5, taste: 5 } }, { rating: { time_to_table: 0, value_for_money: 3, innovation: 2, plating_decoration: 2, taste: 4 } }],
    result = data.reduce(function iter(target, source) {
        Object.keys(source).forEach(function (k) {
            if (source[k] && typeof source[k] === 'object') {
                iter(target[k] = target[k] || {}, source[k]);
                return;
            }
            target[k] = (target[k] || 0) + +source[k];
        });
        return target;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```